# Was I right to post this particular question on Stack Overflow and not GIS?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Recently, I posted this question to Stack Overflow:

[How to find a particular coordinate on a Sentinel image using proj:transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017863/how-to-find-a-particular-coordinate-on-a-sentinel-image-using-projtransform)

Was I right to post it here, or would [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) (GIS) have been a better fit?

I posted it here because I think it is highly programming related, and the available tags were highly related to my problem. I know SO way better than GIS, but it is possible that this judgement was wrong.

Comment: Added more context, I hope it is enough to retract close vote / not to vote for this question to be closed.

Comment: GIS also has programming questions. I would check the [sentinel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentinel) tag to see if you can find something similar there.

Comment: This is a programming question, thus on-topic. But the question is where you find the bigger audience for your issue. When the tags are rarely visited on SO, then GIS might be the better site (when such questions are on-topic there). When you consider asking this question on GIS instead, then also delete the question here. Crossposting on multiple sites isn't that welcomed (see: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)).

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will wait a bit, if it doesn't get answered, I'll delete and post it there.

Comment: Those who voted to close, please explain what "details or clarity" you want, instead of deleting my comments asking for such an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that this question clearly involves a fair amount of programming in Python, I can only say that you were *not wrong* in posting it here... that is, it's on-topic.

That being said, I can't answer whether you would have gotten *better* answers if you had asked it on GIS... I am not familiar with the GIS field or with that Stack Exchange site. *If* the GIS Stack Exchange site allows questions about programming in Sentinel, *and if* it  appears to have an active group of users who read and answer questions tagged with that technology or combination of technologies, then yes, it's likely it would have gotten a good or better-than-SO response there... but that's only conjecture.

Comment: Thank you. Just moved it to GIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/410739/how-to-find-a-particular-coordinate-on-a-sentinel-image-using-projtransform